# How to automatically list directory contents after a CD command?

Tags: unix, command-line

I would like to create a new unix command to automatically list the contents of a directory after a CD command. So far, I've tried several things:

`alias cdls='cd $1 | ls -l'`

`function cdls(){ cd $1; ls -l;}`

Both perform the listing but dont change the working directory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use zsh. Google `zsh {your distribution}` for instructions.

Comment: I tried zsh on windows, it doesn't work. It successfully performs the listing but dont change the working directory.

Comment: Tested again with the `function cdls()...`, and it worked! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

```
Do automatically an ls after every successfull cd:

function cd {
    builtin cd "$@" && ls
}
Go up n levels:

# Usage .. [n]
function .. (){
    local arg=${1:-1};
    local dir=""
    while [ $arg -gt 0 ]; do
        dir="../$dir"
        arg=$(($arg - 1));
    done
    cd $dir #>&/dev/null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

> alias cdls='cd $1 && ls -l'

Your examples are working for me, though (in zsh).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `cd dir/dir/ ; ls` ?

Comment: because I don't want to type '; ls -l' after each cd.

Comment: Hah, fair enough. Look into zsh in that case.