# Shell option for automatically listing all files when cd to a folder in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm really tired of typing `ls`. Is there a command or option in shell that shows you all the files after you `cd` into a folder without having to type `ls`? Thank you!

Original:

```
folder>cd subfolder
subfolder>ls
yu fi sd
```

What I'm expecting:

```
folder>cd subfolder
yu fj sd
subfolder>
```

Note I know I can use
 `cd subfolder;ls`
 but I really do not want to type `ls` as it is very boring.

Basically I was seeking for a command embedded inside shell so that I can turn on or turn off this feature as my wish.

Comment: You can create an alias `alias hello="ls"`. This way, instead of `ls` you'll have to type `hello` :P

Comment: Or you can create a little function that does all in one: `cd` and `ls` --> `f () { cd "$1"; ls }`.

Comment: no i do not want to type "ls", i want all files to be listed as default

Comment: is there already an embedded option inside shell?

Comment: @fedorqui : If op create an alias, i guess it wil be pain later, say when they write a script where this behavior is not desirable  :D

Comment: @sjsam See [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases): "Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the `expand_aliases` shell option is set."

Comment: @BenjaminW. That was new stuff for me. Thankyou :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically list directory contents after a CD command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503455/how-to-automatically-list-directory-contents-after-a-cd-command)

Comment: or install `sl` and then run `cd subfolder; sl`. thats not boring anymore :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. If you want `ls` only after `cd`

   You actually need in `.bashrc` define `cd` as a function using something like:

   ```
   cd() {
       builtin cd $@
       ls
   }
   ```
2. If you want to `ls` after each command in your shell:

   Then set in `.bashrc` something like:

   ```
   prompt_func() {
       export PS1="$(ls)\n$ "
   }
   export PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_func
   ```

Comment: The second solution sets the prompt anew for every command, and it removes any prompt I might have. Why not just `PROMPT_COMMAND=ls`?

Comment: It is also OK. However I have used a function since often in the function you need to do lots of other things for setting PS1. I mean it is just more convinient for me.

Comment: If you want `ls` only when the directory changed (whatever the cause): https://askubuntu.com/a/97766/356625

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not a scripting solution, install [Midnight Commander](https://www.midnight-commander.org/). Run `mc`, and you'll see a listing of files every time you enter a directory. You can use the shell within `mc` interface. You can also toggle the panes using `Ctrl-1` and `Ctrl-2`.

I think scripting solution is not appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function named e.g. `cdls`:

```
cdls () { cd "$1" && ls ;}
```

Run it as:

```
cdls /directory
```

**For example:**

```
$ cdls () { cd "$1" && ls ;} 

$ cdls foo
bar

$ pwd
/home/foobar/foo
```